# Lost my .bash_profile. Is it possible to recover it from Time Machine backups?

Tags: terminal, time-machine, bash

I recently completely reinstalled macOS on my MacBook but I forgot to save my personalised .bash_profile. I was stupid enough not to dump it on Gist for future use, and now I'm looking into restoring it. I have several Time Machine backups on an external SSD-drive, would it be possible to restore this file somehow, and if so, where can I find this file so I can copy it over to my current macOS installation?

Searching through the entire backup folder didn't show me any useful results. I have gone through several threads to try to locate where this file might be saved, but as of now I couldn't come across a good answer which covers my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Find your home folder in Finder , then enter time machine

Answer (score 8):

You do not even need to enter **Time Machine**, although your **Time Machine** drive must be connected and mounted.

In **Terminal**, which by default opens to your `$HOME` *directory*, you can use the following *command*, literally, to copy the `.bash_profile` file to your `$HOME` *directory*:

```bash
cp -av /Volumes/*/Backups.backupdb/*/Latest/*/Users/$USER/.bash_profile .
```

<sub>Note that this *command* assumes there is only one volume attached that has a `Backups.backupdb` directory in its `root` *directory*.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

In Finder: Set to make visible unvisible files, select your home folder,
Enter TimeMachine, select a date before the reinstall, select .bash_profile and restore it.